# iptable string matching to find application type / application layer protoco

Tags: iptables, netfilter

I would like to know is it possible to match the type of applications/application layer protocols using iptables string matching extension?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

If you know a unique string specifically  that application or clients using that application includes it to communication packets.

But if it is encrypted, you probably can not.

Comment: Thank you ibrahim. Do you know where can I find a list of these unique strings? any thing like snort rules....

Comment: I don't think there is such list. Why dont you use snort instead?

Comment: I don't know much about snort but do you think Snort can identify the applications?or it can just identify the attacks?

Comment: Snort inspecting network packets like iptables do. So if you can write a snort rule for the application you want to detect, you can identify.

Comment: BTW some companies developed some tools for specifically that purpose. NAVL is one of them. https://www.proceranetworks.com/hubfs/Datasheets/Procera_DS_NAVL.pdf?t=1479343151691

Comment: Yes Snort can inspect network packets using signatures/rules the tricky part is finding/implementing these rules for an application...
I just found an open project called [ndpi-netfilter](https://github.com/betolj/ndpi-netfilter) which integrates ndpi (deep packet inspection library) with netfiler. I am going to test it, I hope it works....